# TableAdapter Update fails: doesn't allow nulls

Tags: c#, tableadapter

I am trying to update a table, using the update method from my tableadapter, but I am getting the fallowing error:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'isCorrect', table 'info'; column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails.
>   The statement has been terminated.

However I did set the `AllowDBNull` property to True for the isCorrect column.

The update has nothing to do with isCorrect in this case, because the original value for this field is not changed at all (meaning for most cases I just want to update the startDate and endDate; and only for one case I need to update the isCorrect field too). My update query looks like this:

```
UPDATE info
SET userID = @userID, startDate = @startDate, endDate = @endDate, isCorrect = @isCorrect
WHERE (userID = @Original_userID) AND (startDate = @Original_startDate) AND (endDate = @Original_endDate) AND (isCorrect = @Original_isCorrect)
```

How can I fix this problem?

**Edit**

For this I am using a Scheduler Control but for the update I am calling these functions: `testsTableAdapter.Update(testsDataSet);`
`this.testsDataSet.AcceptChanges();`

Comment: Please show the code you execute.

Answer (score 0):

Check the design of **info** table (Database) & verify whether you have checked the checkbox against the "isCorrect" Column to Allow Nulls.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you:

Find the  info `DataTable` in your `DataSet` and select the `isCorrect` column. Then press F4 and Find the `NullValue` property and set it to `Null`.

Let me know if it solves this way.

Answer (score 0):

Your original isCorrect is not the issue here, check if your new isCorrect value is not null. you can insert a breakpoint before the tableadapter method is executed and check what values you are passing to your table adapter. Because if your table doesnot allow null values, when you call on AcceptChange method, it throws an exception.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with an ID column. 
I solved ist by creating this ID column with: IDENTITY(1,1)

Maby not the same setting but it may help others who have the same problem with ID columns.